# How to pass arguments to jQuery widget?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, client-side, jquery-widgets

This is a noob question.

Suppose I have a `jQuery` dialog opened on a button click. The dialog is implemented as a `jQuery` widget:

```
(function ($) {

  $.widget("myApp.myDialog", {

     _create: fnction() {...} // create a dialog

     _init: fnction() {...} // open a dialog    
  })

}(jQuery));
```

I open this dialog on button click as follows:

```
$('#myButton').bind('click', function() { $(this).myDialog(); });
```

So far, so good. I hope it makes sense.

Now I would like to *disable* that button when the dialog is opened and *enable* it when the dialog is closed. How can I pass the button to the dialog widget ?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are looking to make a `dialog` you probably want to pass in `$.ui.dialog` as the 2nd parameter of `$.widget` so you inherit dialog's functionality.

When you create an instance of `myDialog` you can enable / disable the button there.

```
(function($) {
    $.widget('myApp.myDialog', $.ui.dialog, {
        
    });
    
    $('.dialog').myDialog({
        open: function() {
            $('#myButton').prop('disabled', true);
        },
        close: function() {
            $('#myButton').prop('disabled', false);
        }            
    });
}(jQuery));
```

**Example** - http://jsfiddle.net/tj_vantoll/v4sYX/